# How to get map as result of HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, dictionary, hql

i need the hql query that should return the Map as result, I tried hql new map query but it returns the list of map like follows

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    String HQL_QUERY = "select new map(user.id as id, user.fullName as fullName)
    from User user";
    List<Map<String,String>> usersList = session.createQuery(HQL_QUERY).list();
```

if this is the only solution then how do i convert a list of map into a single map without looping, because if the query returns more rows then the looping take more time for convertion. Help me.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using `Criteria` and then a result transformer to create a map. Have a look at [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations) for official documentation. This gives you a clue and you can find more samples on net.

Comment: hi @Ean thank you for the answer but it's similar to what i post. get the list of map and iterate that. It's more cost when i have more rows  ex, if i have millions of users then the iterate take more time.

Comment: If you have millions of records you don't want to load all of them in memory, do you? If yes I suggest rethinking of your approach. Hibernate is not a proper framework to load big chunk of data though. You need to limit your query or use pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a map is not the job of HQL. It's your job. Simply loop over the rows you get from the query:

```
String hql = "select user.id, user.fullName from User user";
List<Object[]> rows = session.createQuery(hql).list();
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
for (Object[] row : rows) {
    result.put((String) row[0], (String) row[1]);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, and if i have millions of user then the looping take more time to load that's why am asking any other solutions. thank you

Comment: How do you think Hibernate would do to create a map without looping through the returned rows? Hibernate is Java code, just as yours. It won't be magically more efficient because Hibernate loops rather than your code. You're pre-optimizing. Do what you have to do, and only optimize if you have a problem, and where you have a problem. If you really have millions of users one day, the loop to create a map will be the least of your problems.

Comment: i know that looping is the solution as i mentioned on my query, just asked to know hibernate have any magics in this case. if yes it's usefull for me and the pre-optimizing is really need in this case because i use the map most of the place in the application . thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use map like below

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select new map(id,username) from UserDetails");
List<?> idUsernameList=query.list();
Iterator<?> iterator = idUsernameList.iterator();
Map row=null;
while(iterator.hasNext()){
   row=(Map)iterator.next();
   System.out.println(row);

}
```